# Get IP of node running a specific resource when demoting master nodes to slaves

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, debian-jessie, corosync

## Setup

I am setting up a HA cluster for a web application with 2 nodes (2 physical servers):

- node1 (current `master` node)
- node2 (current `slave` node)

Using Corosync & Pacemaker I was able to create the cluster and some resources agents including an IP failover and a Webserver (apache).

#### Resources

- `Failover` resource exists on only one node at a time

> Uses a python script to make API calls to my hosting provider in order to update the IP failover destination

- `WebServer` resource exists (as a clone) on every available node

> Standard OCF resource using Apache's `server-status` handler

#### Constraints

- There is a constraint that says that `Failover` and `WebServer` must be running at the same time on a server in order for considering it as available.

## The issue

Now I would like to create a custom resource agent (like I did for the IP failover) that will:

- Switch the mysql instance of the current slave node into a master node
- **Switch the mysql instance of the current master node into a slave node of the new master node**
- Basically do the same for Redis instance

Ideally, the resource would be started on only one node (*master*), and stopped on all other nodes (*slaves*). Therefore, starting the resource would put the current node in `master` mode, and stopping it would put it in `slave` mode.

I made a script that can easily achieve all of these operations. Here's how it works.

Turn local node in *master* mode:

```
# /usr/local/bin/db_failover_switch.sh master
```

Turn local node in *slave* mode:

```
# /usr/local/bin/db_failover_switch.sh slave 123.45.67.89
```

The synopsis is pretty straightforward to understand.
The problem I am facing, is that I obviously need to set the master IP in order for the slave to configure MySQL and Redis services accordingly.

## TL;DR

In case of failover, I want:

- Resource starts on `node2` which becomes `master` node
- **Resource stops on `node1` which becomes `slave` node**

In order to stop the resource (i.e. setting it into slave mode), I need to know the IP address (hostname will do) of the node which has the resource running.

Is there a way I can have a dynamic parameter that Pacemaker will pass to my resource agent? Or maybe can I retrieve the clusters information directly from my resource agent script to know which is the node running a specific resource?

Comment: Which cluster shell are you using? `crmsh`? `cman`?

Comment: I'm using `crm`. But now that I had the time to look deeper into it, I'm starting to think I'm doing this the wrong way. I should probably set up 2 different multiple-state resources for MySQL and Redis, and use heartbeat mysql and redis resources agents.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment I'm not sure if you still want to go that route you had planned for originally, but anyway, here is an input for this:

Using `crm_mon --group-by-node -1` you could get a "one-time" view of the current state of your cluster, grouped by your nodes. The `-1` parameter makes this non-interactive, which means it just displays the data and then exits.

(**Edit:** Maybe using `crm_mon -1` makes parsing in your specific case more easy.)

You could parse this output and act accordingly.

*(Personal note: I would go as well the route you've described in your comment. After all, these are two daemons, so two resources seems reasonable. Also, the resource agents to use exist already. Good luck!)*

Comment: I already explored that idea though, but awkwardly, `crm_mon` (be it interactive or not), does not give more information on nodes other than the node name in the cluster. So yes, I could find out which node is running as *master*, and use some hard-coded table to establish an associative array... But that's way too heavy. I'll go with the separated resources agents that already exist in heartbeat, like you pointed out. By the way, interesting to see [how they retrieve master's IP](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/mysql#L798-L813)

Comment: @JordanBecker In my setups, I'm using the hostname as the name of the node, but yeah, it seems a bit "hackish".

Comment: That would for sure be better than my current "primary" and "secondary" node names... But for now it's the least of my concerns, I'm having a hard time trying to setup properly the MySQL master/slave setup... Will probably ask another question on SF...

Comment: @JordanBecker Ping me if you do, maybe I could help.

Comment: I just opened a new question [over here](http://serverfault.com/questions/753551/multi-state-mysql-master-slave-pacemaker-resource-fails-to-launch-on-cluster-nod), would be great if you could have a look!